# How do I do regular Expression Type Matching on IP adresses in SQL Server

Tags: regex, sql-server-2005

Here is the problem at hand.

Say I have a table :

mytable

```
Area    | UserIP
------------------------    
Fontana | 192.233.23.44
Fontana | 192.233.45.68
Fontana | 192.233.46.87
Fontana | 78.65.14.36
Fontana | 78.65.36.15
North Carolina | 284.65.25.4
```

My goal is to run a query and return for each area and first two sets of numbers in an IP, the count.

In table form it would look like this

ResultTable

```
Area    | UserIP  | Count
---------------------------    
Fontana | 192.233 | 3
Fontana | 78.65 | 2
North Carolina | 284.65 | 1
```

Thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select area, 
PARSENAME(userip,4) + '.' + PARSENAME(userip,3) UserIp, 
COUNT(*)
from mytable
group by area, PARSENAME(userip,4) + '.' + PARSENAME(userip,3)
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06d2f/1)